# Finding cookie name and value from a Set-Cookie header

Tags: cookies, http-headers, setcookie

I have been learning about HTTP headers recently. I read about the Set-Cookie sent by the server and its uses. I read that the cookies come as a key-value pair.

Scenario: I went to myntra.com and read the cookie that was sent by the server. It was

> set-
>   cookie:akaas_myntra_SegmentationLabel=1521628193~rv=72~id=40f22ddea4510d19c45d8140b7a94c1e~rn=PWA; path=/; Expires=Wed, 21 Mar 2018 10:29:53 GMT

There are multiple equal to ('=') signs in the cookie and I do not know how to derive the name and value from it. Thank you for your help.

Name =? Value =?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are separated by ; And than the name is in front the first = sign everything behind is the value.

Comment: Thank you so much, was wondering the same. Wanted to confirm it.